# In App Purchase Non-Consumable - Performance - App Completeness iOS 14.2

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit, in-app-purchase-receipt

Issue I am facing is this below:

"We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 14.2 on Wi-Fi."

"When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead."

I have implemented in-App Purchase (Non-Consumable), Its working perfectly fine in Buy and Restore etc. Apple Rejects with the above reason.

What I am doing:

1. Using SwiftyStoreKit
2. Click Buy Button
3. SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo
4. SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct
5. On Success ( SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction )

Restore:

1. Click Restore
2. SwiftyStoreKit.restorePurchases

Please let me know if need more information or code etc and what I am doing wrong which rejected the app.

Apple Recently Replied me as well this below message:

"Regarding purchasing in-app purchases, we continue to be unable to buy the full version of the app. When we tap on the button to buy, the app continues to load indefinitely.

We are not able to provide feedback on app concepts or features, but we recommend evaluating your suggestions against the App Store Review Guidelines, as well as the iOS Developer Program License Agreement (PLA), and the iOS Human Interface Guidelines."

Comment: did you get solution to this

Comment: @AmitVerma no not yet. Don't know whats the issue. People are saying that try to upload again but if that rejected again then it will make app approval process lengthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the Solution for this. When ever you receive error something like above, here are the steps you need to check and do.

1. Check first your In-App Purchase Implementation. Are you doing it correctly, ending the transaction etc.
2. Check what is the latest version of iOS supported by your XCode. If its lower than the shown in the issue like in mine ( xcode ios version was 14.0 and issue with 14.2).

For that you need to just download the latest XCode which support that iOS Version and make a build and then submit for review. It will surely work.